# How do you get the field name, instead of the value, from the model?

Tags: yii

Suppose I have a Model Class named Anything, in Yii, and all I want is to get not the field value, but the field name, how could I do that?

Because using something like:

```
$anything = new Anything;
$anything->field_name;
```

Returns the value of that field, which is the purpose for that, still, if all you want is the string of the name of the field, how could you do that?

I tried using:

```
$anything->attributes;
```

But it just returns an array of field names, I want to try and get a specific value as a defined constant.

What I want to do is use the $_POST with specific and practical use, so I wouldn't need to use:

```
$_POST["Model_name"];
```

Instead I could use:

```
$_POST[Anything::model()->name][Anything::model()->field_name->name]
```

Which seems a lot better than "" and '' here and there. Mostly because I'm trying to set multiple fieldsets of different Models in the same formulary.

So if I could use:

```
$_POST[Anything::model()->name][Anything::model()->field_name->name];
```

and

```
$_POST[Something::model()->name][Something::model()->field_name->name]
```

and

```
$_POST[Godspeed::model()->name][Godspeed::model()->field_name->name]
```

It would save a lot of problems I might had in the future.

Comment: You need a key to open a locked door, why you want to find that key while you had it in your hand already? You should tell the task what you intend to do?

Comment: Once, while using Zend I noticed that I could change the field name while I didn't need to do that to the variable, so I could use something like:
$fieldname_A = "fieldname_B"
And go on with it, I didn't noticed a similar structure in Yii.
But I'm going to put on what I want, just a second.

Comment: I really wonder, what you try to achieve. While working with Yii for almost 5 years now, i *never* had the above requirement. You should use [massive assignment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#securing-attribute-assignments) whenever possible. You almost never have to touch specific attributes in `$_POST`.

Comment: That's the point, there are fields in the Model that should get data automatically, like the ID of the user logged, the current date_time, so they are fields that will not receive inputs from the user, but from the application itself, of course, once they pass the validation.
But really? I don't see why is it so hard to get the field name using a simple process, as it's just the name of the field, a simple attribute, I believe this should be inductive for any case.
Unless I put it as hidden in the form, which may work.

Comment: The reason people are having such a hard time answering you is that you are acting like there is just one field name for a model, when in fact there could be hundreds.  How is the application to determine which field name you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, Murphy, no, that's not the problem, because, as I wrote before, I've set an example using 'Anything::model->fieldname->name' the name here stands for the name of the field as a constant, not as a value itself, I don't see why is it so hard to get that kind of information when it's inductive that you have it in the model itself. How is the app to determine which field name I am looking for? That's simple, I'm telling it the field I'm using... in return I want the field name, as it could've been a nickname or so.
That's pretty common in Zend framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $strModelName = 'ModelName'; //dynamic - whatever model name you put in it

        $find_id = 3;
        $record = $strModelName::model()->findByPK($find_id); //it's same with ModelName::model()->findByPK(3)

        foreach($record->attributes as $key=>$value){
            var_dump($_POST[$strModelName][$key]); //get value corresponding to given key
        }
```

Btw, you still need check whether the model is exist or not
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22790-check-if-model-exists/

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I meant... you see, I have this Model already, what I want to know it's a way I can get the field name having sure I didn't wrote it wrong while on a different controller.
You see, it's not like the fields change names every day, but I want to make sure that if I change the field name in the Model, I will get a bug thrown up in the screen anytime saying:
"Property "Anything.field_name" is not defined."

So it's easier to find the bug and solve it.

Comment: @RafaelLima if you make error reporting strict, it will throw this kind of error automatically. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php